# Connect two Android phones with USB cable

Tags: android

I want to connect two phones with USB cable and use ADB command like `adb devices`, `adb shell` from one phone, just like between PC and an Android phone. I tried with OTG supported cable which has two micro USB plugin, but it didn't work. Trying with another common cable (not OTG) with two micro USB plugin didn't work too. `adb devices` always fails with message "no device is attached at all" in both Phone A and Phone B.

Anyone has experience about this? What kind of cable is needed?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible between some phones.

1. But at least one of them must have OTG support.
2. and you need an OTG connector.(also a USB cable)

Check the following link for detailed explanation:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2640456

---

I'll be quoting the detailed explanation just in case the link gets broken:

> Yes if u need to transfer data between two phones like GBs of data n u
>   u have atleast one phone that supports OTG and u been looking for pc
>   to transfer data or been trying to use wifi share apps trust me this
>   is a solution to npc-less transfers and EVEN U CAN BORTOW YOUR FRIENDS
>   BATTERY CHARGE IF YOU ARE RUNNING LOW ON BATTERY!!!!!!
>
> With just an OTG n a USB cable you CAN transfer data and battery
>   charge between two phones!!
>
> youl need:
>
> A) 2 phones (atleast one with OTG support)
>
> B)OTG connector
>
> C)Usb cable.
>
> D)file explorer like es file explorer
>
> Here on il refer the phone that contains data and charge as "host"
>   phone n to phone to be transferred as "second" phone.
>
> If your second phone is a xperia device then go to settings ->xperia
>   connectivity ->usb connectivity
>
> Change the usb connectivity mode from "MTP" to "MSC"..
>
> Steps:
>
> 1)Just connect OTG cable to host phone...
>
> 2)The second phone connect usb cable.. N the pc usb part.. Which u
>   connect to pc...connect it to the OTG
>
> *REMEMBER* 3)In the second phone select ur mass storage option!!
>
> 4) use file explorer (I used Es file explorer coz its the best I used)
>
> BINGO.. On host phone u can see the memory card of second phone as
>   "usbdisk"...plus.. The second phone will charge battery from first
>   phone...
>
> Worked on
>
> my xperia Z1 as host and micromax a65 as second phone..
>
> my xperia Z1 as host and micromax a116 as second phone..
>
> my xperia Z1 as host and xperia M as second phone..
>
> my xperia M as host and xperia z1 as second phone..
>
> Well all permutations of these phones..

Comment: hi, Metehan, thanks your answer. In my note2 and note3, second phone will charge from the first phone. But i cannot find disk of second phone in the first phone. How to set phone two to mass storage? thanks.

Comment: Hi, Metehan, I also need to test adb command, Did you to this before?

Comment: You can check this link on how to set your phone to mass storage: http://www.device-recovery.com/how-to-connect-android-devices-to-pc-with-usb-mass-storage-mode

Comment: hi, Metehan, i just try to modify devices according to your link. it still fails to find disk of second. :(. some tools which can set mass storage mode need root phone.

Answer (score 0):

I never tried this. But after reading the post, i think you have to save settings in your second phone as mass storage. Then you can access this phone's memory in the host device. In the host device have you installed any file explorer like file manager or es explorer. Then i think you should be able to see this phone's memory. 
Thanks
shiva

Comment: How can you do that?